# Python-sphinx: ignore text in .rst file

Tags: python, github, python-sphinx

I have a README.rst on GitHub that is also incorporated into the Sphinx-generated documentation for a Python project. I would like to include a note at the top of the file that will be shown on GitHub (which simply renders the .rst) but not shown in the Sphinx-generated docs.

I know that I can include a comment in an `.rst` file using `.. blah blah blah`, but is there some way that I can include a line that is only considered a comment by Sphinx? (Or, have that line otherwise ignored by Sphinx.)

Comment: wrong tag for sphinx, you should put "python-sphinx"

Comment: Thanks! Change made.

Comment: Given that both Sphinx and GitHub would be interpreting it as RST, I don't see how you could have something that was a comment in one but not the other.

Comment: Well, you can have things like ``.. note::`` that do things in Sphinx but don't do much in normal RST.
And I suppose it doesn't need to be a comment, I would just like Sphinx to not include the text in the final generated docs.

Answer (score 3):

You want a line in `.rst` file included on GitHub but ignored in your Sphinx documentations.

It could be achieved using `ifconfig` directive [sphinx.ext.ifconfig – Include content based on configuration](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/ifconfig.html?highlight=include#module-sphinx.ext.ifconfig) this way.

In your `conf.py` file check that `sphinx.ext.ifconfig` extension is enabled

```
# conf.py
extensions = [
    ...
    'sphinx.ext.ifconfig',
    ...
]
```

and register a variable

```
# conf.py
# custom variables
def setup(app):
    app.add_config_value(name='show_github_hote', default=True, rebuild='env')

# uncomment in Sphinx doc to hide the note
# show_github_hote = False
```

then in your `.rst` file

```
.. ifconfig:: show_github_hote

    THIS NOTE IS FOR GITHUB ONLY.

    Use bigger indentation for the note.

Further text with smaller indent.
```

If `show_github_hote` var is not set the value is `True` by default and the note should be printed. To hide the note set `show_github_hote = False` in `conf.py`.